# Can IG Graph API get the users who likes a post?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I am studying IG Graph API, and I couldn't find out how to get the users who likes a post.

In this page, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-media , there is only like_count field.

I'm thinking whether it's unable to do this or I overlooked it in the doc.